# openpyxl load_workbook error: iteration over non sequence type

Tags: python

when i try to load_worbook (its a empty xlsx file) it get a error.

```
import openpyxl as op

wb = op.load_workbook(filename = 'C:\EXCEL TEST\TS.xlsx')
```

error

```
Runtime error (TypeErrorException): iteration over non-sequence of type Sequence

Traceback:
  line 154, in find, "C:\RhinoPython\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py"
  line 163, in findall, "C:\RhinoPython\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py"
  line 142, in read_strings, "C:\RhinoPython\openpyxl\reader\excel.py"
  line 269, in read, "C:\RhinoPython\openpyxl\reader\excel.py"
  line 312, in load_workbook, "C:\RhinoPython\openpyxl\reader\excel.py"
  line 14, in script
```

Any tip is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can try following sometimes its getting error because cells containing formulas not data. try following and see read_only=True is optional by the way

`op.load_workbook(<file name>,data_only=True,read_only=True)`

For further reading follow this [link](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html)

Replace file path value `C:\EXCEL TEST\TS.xlsx` with `C:\\EXCEL TEST\\TS.xlsx`

Comment: Unfortunatly i get the same error and the xlsx file is completly empty nothing is inside. But thanks for your help

Comment: `sheet=wb.active` use this after loading

Comment: Replace file path value `C:\EXCEL TEST\TS.xlsx` with `C:\\EXCEL TEST\\TS.xlsx`

Comment: Thanks again, but still the same error. I dont understand the error it normaly appears if a loop iterates over a non list object

Comment: empty workbooks are allowed. i think probably the file is not getting to the library move around the paths and see first put that file into the same directory and test cheers.

Comment: i also reinstalles the module openpyxl via pip (before i have installed it mauelly) and have tried what you mentioned but still the same error. Aslo i tried to change the file to unicode-8

Comment: What is the python version you are running? And can you show me the code that you’ve tried so far? And the folder structure! (Tree view)

Comment: I use ironpython 2.7.8.0 i guess this is the main reason for the issue will check that out

Comment: Better upgrade to python 3 unless you have specific reason to use 2